# Laravel : Import excel data does not match the amount

Tags: excel, laravel, import

I want to import data from laravel to DB, but this doesn't run enough. i mean like i import 120 data, but my project just can proccess data 100 from my excel data. this is my controller code:

```
  public function postImport(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $sheet = $request->jenis;
    $import = new InterfaceImport();
    $upload = Excel::import($import, $file);
    $data = $import->showDataExcelSheet($sheet);
    if($sheet=='mstSupplier'){
        foreach($data as $x => $dt){
            $supp = interfaceData::SpUploadSupplier('Add',$this->kodeToko,0,$data[$x]['namasupplier'],$data[$x]['singkatansupplier'],
            $data[$x]['tipesupplier'],$data[$x]['alamatsupplier'],$data[$x]['kodepossupplier'],$data[$x]['notelpsupplier'],
            $data[$x]['nofax'],$data[$x]['emailsupplier'],$data[$x]['contaksupplier'],$data[$x]['hp'],'insert');
        } 
        return redirect()->back();
   
}
```

and this is my import file, and this is my import file, and this is my import file

```
   <?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use App\Models\interfaceData;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeSheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
class InterfaceImport implements ToArray, WithHeadingRow, WithEvents
{
    public $sheetNames;
    public $sheetData;
   
    public function __construct(){
        $this->sheetNames = [];
        $this->sheetData = [];
    }
    public function array(array $array){
        $this->sheetData[$this->sheetNames[count($this->sheetNames) - 1]] = $array;
    }
    public function registerEvents(): array {
        return [
            BeforeSheet::class => function(BeforeSheet $event) {
                $this->sheetNames[] = $event->getSheet()->getTitle();
            },
        ];
    }
    public function getSheetNames() {
        return $this->sheetNames;
    }
    public function getSheetData() {
        return $this->sheetData;
    }
    public function showDataExcelSheet($sheet) {
        return $this->sheetData[$sheet];
    }
}
```

Comment: `i mean like i import 120 data, but my project just can proccess data 100 from my excel data` <<<=== this one is very important. I would re-write the controller code. Let the import ass do its work. Explain if you have more than 1 tab in the excel file. Put a try/catch block around your import class and check your log file. If there's an error in the log, then copy/paste the entire stacktrace of that error in your original question